How to store the script-generated DOM in memory with React
I am currently working on a component that decide whether to render/hide a Script-generated Video Player given the window size using a customised hook that listening to the resizing of the window with optimisation.
I am currently facing a problem that the script(more specifically, jwplayer) seems to restrict the client to render only once each refresh, which means when the jwplayer was hidden, there is no way for it to be re-renderred.
Is there anyway I can store the script-generated dom somewhere and directly use it when required.
The way I am currently working on is:

const PipVideoScript = () => {
  const renderedContent = useMemo(() => {
    return (
      <div
        dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{
          __html:
            '<script src="https://content.jwplatform.com/players/123456789.js"></script>',
        }}
      />
    );
  }, []);

  return renderedContent;
};

const MemoPipVideoScript = React.memo(PipVideoScript);
export default MemoPipVideoScript;


const PipVideo = ({ maxDisplaySize, minDisplaySize }: PVProps) => {
  const [display, setDisplay] = useState<boolean>(true);
   const screenSize = useScreenSize();

  useEffect(() => {
    // some logics to setDisplay
  }, [screenSize.width];
  

  return (
    display && (
      <div>
        <PipVideoScript />
        <div
          className="absolute top-0 right-0 hover:cursor-pointer"
          onClick={() => {
            setDisplay(false);
          }}
        >
          <X />
        </div>
      </div>
    )
  );


What I expect was the Script was renderred once and the generated DOM stored somewhere and can be reused.
Thanks.
